# split string (full path to file)

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String = "/dir1/dir2/file1.sth"

or

String = "/dir1/file2.sth"

and other.

I need to do something like this:

path: /dir1/dir2/

and

file name: file1.sth

How do that in Java?

Comment: Easy, by writing code.

Comment: find last Index Of / and split from there.

Comment: find the index of the last '/' and use that as a boundary for the split?

Comment: well given that there are functions for path manipulation in e.g. Python I don't see why this question is getting downvotes and sardonic comments

Comment: thx I knew how do that but it was wrong question. I dont knew function  :) Thank You.

Comment: @Nicolas78 Given that Java also has path manipulation as part of the built-in class that handles paths, I don't see how your comment works.

Comment: @hexafraction well that's the kind of info that you'd expect as an answer to this question, not "by writing code"

Answer (score 1):

Make a file object based on the string. You cam then call getName() to get the name. You can call getParent() to get the path before it

See these docs:  docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 0):

If you define a File object with that path (/dir1/file2.sth) you can easily split filename and the address:

```
File f=new File("/dir1/file2.sth");

//get file name
f.getName();

//get path
f.getParentFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath = "/dir1/dir2/file1.sth";
    String[] components = filePath.split("/");

    String path = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < components.length-1; i++)
    {
       path += components[i] + "/";
    }
    String file = components[components.length-1];

    System.out.println("Path name: " + path);
    System.out.println("File name: " + file);
}
```

That will get you what you want, and it also shows you the output.